# Howto: Applying a Style defined in generic.xaml to a UserControl? (WPF)

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, generic.xaml

I've created a style in generic.xaml that i want to use in my project on several UserControls. In the same way i have defined a style for a custom control and this one works so it seems generic.xaml is loaded, this is the defined style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}" x:Key="ServiceStyle" x:Name="ServiceStyle">
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
                <Border Name="border" CornerRadius="20"
                        Margin="10"
                        BorderThickness="5"
                        BorderBrush="Black">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But now i want to use this style but i cannot get it to work. i've tryed adding it as a style parameter to a custom instance of UserControl in the following way:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Netcarity"
    xmlns:CustomControls="clr-namespace:Netcarity.CustomControls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" x:Name="Portier_deur" x:Class="Netcarity.UserControlPortier"
    Height="600" Width="800" MouseDown="UserControl_MouseDown" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded" mc:Ignorable="d"
    Style="{StaticResource ServiceStyle}">
```

however this gives me a note that the resource ServiceStyle could not be found. When trying to run there is a runtime error on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Retagged, assuming you wanted 'WPF' and not 'WFP'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Generic.xaml is not the right place to store styles for non custom controls. Somewhere i found the hint to put the syle in App.xaml instead of generic.xaml and this worked directly. So it seams Generic.xaml can only be used to store styles for customControls.
Maybe someone can add a more educated reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

When Generic.xaml use ComponentResourceKey.